# Calling QGIS export features window through a Python plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, export, gui

I am developing a QGIS plugin in Python and I need some help to efficiently save my output layer to a CSV. I understand that by right-clicking on the layer and going to "Export -> Save features as" opens the window that enables me to save my output as a CSV. This window is shown below.

[image: Expected save layer window]

But I expect people who are new to QGIS (or GIS even) to use this tool and they might not be able to find this saving option straight away, hence thinking of adding that feature to the plugin itself. What I would ideally want is to bring up this inbuilt saving window (shown above) through my python code. So, when the user presses a button on the GUI, this window would come up straightaway. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Maybe there is a processing algorithm of the form `processing.runalg(appropriate arguments)` that would enable me to do this?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to save a vector layer to CSV using `processing.run` is to use `native:savefeatures` tool.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
output = "C:/path/to/output.csv"

processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
               {'INPUT': layer,
                'OUTPUT': output})
```

If you want to specify other parameters, you can use `'LAYER_OPTIONS'`.

```
# separate individual options with semicolon
layer_options = 'SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON;GEOMETRY=AS_WKT'

processing.run("native:savefeatures", 
               {'INPUT': layer,
                'OUTPUT': output,
                'LAYER_OPTIONS': layer_options})
```